# Xcode files are not generated Release

Tags: xcode, macos

I have ceased to create files Release build, while he is going to project but there is no file in the folder Release. or creates a link with the original is not present or where
a few days ago all worked, and now working on two computers the same

What's the problem? what happened? neither of which I did not do

Comment: which version of xcode are you using? In general, you should do an Archive build, then generate a signed app from the organizer using the archive

Comment: I found where it is, but does not work yet ((
says "no developer ids ere available for signing", try to download from the Dev Center - does not work

Comment: I go in circles on this page - http://joxi.ru/DdIfUxjKTJCgTUlHBbw 
this is what is the nightmare that happened I do not understand